# Display text after order is placed woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to display some text after my woocommerce order has been placed.

I have the following piece of code , but it doesnt seem to work. What could be the issue?

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'simplicate_send', 10, 1);

function simplicate_send($order_id){
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text/) hook instead?

Comment: @rpm192 i dont just want to display text, my end goal is to send data to an api. But i want to be able to test things out by printing it out on the screen and the printing out part is not working

Answer (score 0):

please try below code in functions.php

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom',10,1); 

 function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
      $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     //whatever you dispaly text here 
      // echo "hello";
      $url = 'http://localhost/html/wordpress3/?page_id=501'; // redirect thank you page
        if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
          wp_safe_redirect( $url );
           exit;
          }
      }
```